# Is it possible to use reflection to get names of variables passed to a function in via this?

Tags: .net, reflection

```
public static void ShouldNotBeNull<T>(this T actualValue)
{
    Assert.IsFalse(actualValue == null, "Object is null, and should not be null.") ;
}
```

I would like to provide a variable name in the error string on my tests. I have this as an extension method. Is it possible to get the real parameter name of the variable being passed in?

Comment: and what to do if you get an expression passed in? e.g.: `obj1.providevalue(obj2, obj3.i + obj4.j).ShouldNotBeNull()`.

Comment: You can use `Assert.IsNotNull(actualValue)` to make your code read a little better.

Comment: I'd really just go with @dlev's suggestion here...

Comment: @Vlad - That's a good question, I didn't consider that. Ideally it would get the name of the method/object the extension method is called on. In your example I believe "providevalue" would be ideal - I could do a check to see if it's a method and adjust the text returned to reflect that it's a method returning null.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve this working with [Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) instead?

Comment: This could be easily achieved with C++ using a macros, but not with C#..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option I've [written up before](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/12/09/quot-magic-quot-null-argument-testing.aspx) is using anonymous types. For example, you'd have:

```
public void Foo(string x, string y, string z) // x and z must not be null
{
     new { x, z }.AssertNoNullElements();
}
```

with a generic `AssertNotNull` method which performs some reflection etc once, and caches the property accesses as delegates in order to hit performance as little as possible.

It's not something I'd generally recommend though. It's not refactor-proof, it creates a new object on each call, and it's generally a bit of an abuse of anonymous types. Admittedly if this is *only* for tests, the performance aspect isn't as bad...

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
public static void ShouldNotBeNull<T>(this T actualValue, string variableName)
{
    Assert.IsFalse(actualValue == null, variableName + " is null, and should not be null.") ;
}
```

Comment: Really?  You don't trust the caller enough to pass a non-null value but you trust them enough to pass in the correct variable name for that same value?

Comment: Well, writing `obj.ShouldNotBeNull(var, "var");` should be simple.

Comment: it's silly looking, error prone, and really no simpler than the caller checking for null themselves

Answer (score -1):

No, the caller may very well not even have a variable name assigned to the 'this' parameter or any other parameter